# Mongodb - Error after turning fork mode on

Tags: mongodb

I am working on installing mongodb on remote server I managed  to install everything and tested it.

But when I tried to enable fork mode to make it run in the background via the command

`mongod --config  mongod.config`

**mongod.config**

```
systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: "etc/mongod.log"
 logAppend: true
storage:
 dbPath: "data/db"
 journal:
  enabled: false
processManagement:
 fork: true
net:
 bindIp: 127.0.0.1
 port: 27017
setParameter:
 enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

this command is run successfully but when trying to run `mongo`
I get this error

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-09-30T01:31:07.048-0700 I -        [thread1] Invariant failure !driverName.empty() && !driverVersion.empty() && !osType.empty() && !osName.empty() && !osArchitecture.empty() && !osVersion.empty() src/mongo/rpc/metadata/client_metadata.cpp 350
2017-09-30T01:31:07.048-0700 I -        [thread1] 

***aborting after invariant() failure


2017-09-30T01:31:08.207-0700 F -        [thread1] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

> Note: everything is working fine without fork mode

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Clarification:  If you take out the processManagement/fork lines and restart the server (in the foreground), then start the CLI (mongo shell), it works?

Comment: Yes this what happens exactly